# SwiftUI Landmarks App Tutorial Screen Navigates Back When Toggle Favorite

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm following this [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) and downloaded the [project files](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/e0e45d9449/HandlingUserInput.zip).

I built and ran the complete project without any modifications. In the app, if I:

1. Toggle "Show Favorites Only" on in the list view
2. Tap into the "Turtle Rock" or "Chilkoot Trail" detail view
3. In the detail view, I toggle the favorite button (a yellow star icon)

The screen will jump back to the list view by itself.

But if I tap into the detail view of the last item ("St. Mary Lake") in the list view, I can toggle the yellow star button on and off and still stay in the same detail view.

Can anyone explain this behavior? What do I need to do to stay in the detail view without being forced to navigate back to the list view?

Comment: I'm having the same problem in my application too, it seems like it doesn't jump back to the `list` when you toggle the last available element. Perhaps it's a bug? I believe the expected behavior is that it doesn't jump back to the `list` because it's not visible. Xcode 11.4 iOS 13.4

Comment: Gosh... this is effect of fix for that warning from previous Xcode versions - *[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy*... At least then, Xcode 11.2,  it worked. Yes, this is a bug of SwiftUI... need to think about workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, actually it is SwiftUI defect, the View being out of view hierarchy must not be refreshed (ie. `body` called) - it should be updated right after next appearance. (I submitted feedback #FB7659875, and recommend to do the same for everyone affected - this is the case when duplicates are better)

Meanwhile, below is possible temporary workaround (however it will continue work even after Apple fix the issue, so it is safe). The idea is to use local view state model as intermediate between view and published property and make it updated only when view is visible.

Provided only corrected view to be replaced in mentioned project.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 - no unexpected "jump back"

[image: demo]

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData

    @State private var landmarks = [Landmark]() // local model
    @State private var isVisible = false        // own visibility state
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Show Favorites Only")
                }
                
                ForEach(landmarks) { landmark in
                    if !self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
                                .environmentObject(self.userData)
                        ) {
                            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onReceive(userData.$landmarks) { array in // observe external model
                if self.isVisible {
                    self.landmarks = array    // update local only if visible
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.isVisible = true         // track own state
                self.landmarks = self.userData.landmarks
            }
            .onDisappear { self.isVisible = false } // track own state
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because in the "main" list you toggled to "show only favorites". then you change in the detail the favorites (so it is no favorite landmark anymore) and because in swiftui the source of truth was changed (favorite) this item was removed from the main list and so it cannot be shown in the detail anymore because it is no member of the main list anymore, so the detail view just navigates back and show the favorite items only.

Comment: Have you tried the very last item in the main list view? Why is its behavior different from all the other items?

Comment: ok, you are right - this is not what i would expect....so looks like an Apple bug