# How do I update a CoreData object in a detail view correctly?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to have simple app that has a sorted list of items. Clicking on each item goes into a detail view, where clicking another button updates a field of an item, which should redraw the original list.

The list view is given by:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context 

    @State private var itemName: String = ""

    // get all data, sorted by date
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Item.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.lastEdited, ascending: true)]
    ) var allItems: FetchedResults<Item>



    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach (allItems) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.context)) {
                        Text(item.name ?? "No name given")
                    } // nav link

                }


            }
    }
}
```

and the detail view is given by:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct DetailView: View {


    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

    var item: FetchedResults<Item>.Element

    var body: some View {

        Button (action: {
            self.updateDate(item: self.item)

            }) {
                Text("Press me!")
            }

    } // body

    func updateDate(item: Item) {
        item.lastEdited = Date()
    } // func

} // DetailView
```

Pressing the "Press Me" button on the detail view causes the update to work, and the list view to update, but this happens when I press the button:

1. A new screen with the detail view is shown
2. It goes back to the list view

Why does (1) happen? How do I avoid this?

I have Item defined as an Entity in my xcdatamodeld

Comment: In `ContentView` you have `destination: DetailView(item: item).envir...` Where is `item` defined? Do you mean to pass `recipe` instead?

Comment: [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61153180/12299030) should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var item: FetchedResults<Item>.Element
```

To

```
@ObservedObject var item: Item
```

It likely happens because the parent is redrawing.

Comment: This actually solved the issue very well, but I don't really understand why though. Wouldn't the parent redrawing still stop the detail view from being rendered? Why does this make any difference?

Comment: All CoreData objects are ObservableObjects. By wrapping it properly you allow SwiftUI to render only what is needed. If it solves it would you accept the answer?

Answer (score -1):

in DetailView, where you make changes try this. It will save the changes you've made.

```
do {
    try self.context.save()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: @JoepBeusenberg, until you haven't saved the data, it won't be updated in any other screen

Comment: also look at the question title "How do I update a CoreData object in a detail view correctly?", to update correctly, save correctly is part of it.

Comment: This issue at hand is that the navigation changes on update of the data. So maybe yes, saving is a part of doing it right, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: yes, but only if you correctly mark the field as `@ObservedObject`. So it's a valuable addition, but it doesn't answer the question.