# Core Data and Xcode Previews: How to Pass FetchResults<T> to a View in Xcode Previews

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a View in SwiftUI called "MyListsView". It requires lists which is of type "FetchedResults" to be passed.

```
struct MyListsView: View {
    
    let lists: FetchedResults<MyList>
}
```

The main issue is that how can I use it in the Xcode Previews. The main reason is that in Xcode Previews, I cannot use the @FetchRequest property wrapper. @FetchRequest property wrapper allows me to create FetchResults.

```
 static var previews: some View {
            
           
            
            MyListsView(lists: HOW TO PASS FetchResults<MyList> HERE  )
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, CoreDataProvider.shared.viewContext)
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to use `FetchedResults<MyList>`? How about an array, e.g. `[MyList]`?

Comment: I don't think I have to use FetchedResults. I was just using it because it is provided when I use @FetchRequest property wrapper. So, it makes it easy to perform Core Data fetch requests in the View.

Comment: If you pass the result to a subview using, e.g. `MyListsView(lists: Array(lists))`, then it'll be easy for you to initialise it when using in a preview

Comment: Thanks! I would like to keep it FetchResults<MyList> because FetchResults object allows you to take advantage of the built-in Core Data change tracking and automatic updates that come with it.

Comment: FetchedResults should be a wrapper and it doesn’t come from the previous view

Comment: Thanks! One solution might be to pass a NSFetchRequest to the MyListsView and then construct a FetchedResults based on the request.

Comment: All CoreData objects are observable objects just wrap with “@ObeservedObject” to see changes you are over complicating something very simple

Comment: @loremipsum Can you give an example of that? I'm not sure how that would work

Comment: @AshleyMills I didn’t make that comment is response to your comments, they work together the OP said that they pass FetchResults so they can observe but that isn’t needed. There is one particular answer that would make this a duplicate that I couldn’t find in my history. The single object is passed like any other ObservableObject, there is no difference.

Comment: @AshleyMills https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164583/how-do-i-update-a-coredata-object-in-a-detail-view-correctly/68347755#68347755

Comment: In this case the OP wants to pass a collection of ‘MyList’ objects, rather than a single object as in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [Structure your app for SwiftUI previews](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10149/) from WWDC 2020, at 18:00 he introduces the concept of an "Intermediate View", e.g.

```
struct MyListsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    struct MyListViewContainer: View {

        @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
        private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

        var body: some View {
            MyListsView(lists: items)
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        MyListViewContainer()
       .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

Note: be sure to use the preview singleton of your `PersistenceController` when previewing.