# Updating an @ObservedObject of the MainView from the DetailView forces the exit from the DetailView

Tags: firebase, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I use a list of lists as a structure, in the MainView I show the lists and through a NavigationLink I show the DetailView of each list which contains a list of objects. 
From the DetailView i can add or delete these objects and when I do so I also update the Firebase database.
The problem is that the observed object is a class which has a listener to the database and every time the Db gets updated then the MainView seems to be recreated and the consequence is that the DetailView goes back to the MainView.
Is there a way to prevent the observed object from updating the MainView while it's not on the screen or to remove the listener when clicking on the NavigationLink so that the MainView doesn't get update until the user goes back?

Comment: please show us your code. this is not a "we code for you for free"-platform, but a "we help you with your provided code" and it should be runnable and compilable. please read and consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [The problem investigation & workaround approach provided in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61153180/12299030)

Comment: Thank you both. 
I decided not to share the code because I thought it was more of Structural problem instead of a simple error in my code, but thanks for the link I will make sure to read the article.
@Asperi I think that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!