# SwiftUI dismisses the detail view when an NSManagedObject subclass instance changes in a way that moves it to a different section of a fetch request?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

[The sample app](https://github.com/genebogdanovich/SwiftUINavigationViewIssue) is a default SwiftUI + Core Data template with two modifications. Detail for `Item` is a separate view where the user can change the `timestamp`. And sectioned fetch request is used as opposed to a regular one.

```swift
@SectionedFetchRequest(
    sectionIdentifier: \.monthAndYear, sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.timestamp)]
) private var items: SectionedFetchResults<String, Item>

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(items) { section in
            Section(header: Text(section.id)) {
                ForEach(section) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ItemDetail(item: item)
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!.formatted())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ItemDetail: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    
    @State private var isPresentingDateEditor = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!.formatted())")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Button(item.timestamp!.formatted()) {
                        isPresentingDateEditor = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingDateEditor) {
                if let date = Binding($item.timestamp) {
                    DateEditor(date: date)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The problem arises when the user changes the `timestamp` on an `Item` to a different month. The detail view dismisses behind the model view arbitrarily. However, the issue is not present if the user changes the `timestamp` to a day within the same month. It does not matter whether we use a sheet or a full-screen cover. When I was debugging this I noticed that **any change of the `NSManagedObject` subclass instance that will change the section in which it is displayed will dismiss the detail view arbitrarily**. I’m expecting to stay on the detail view even if I change the `timestamp` to a different month.

What is the root cause of this issue and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Code would be helpful here.

Comment: I added essential bits. The rest is in the sample project.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because the `NavigationLink` is no longer active because it has moved to a different section so it has a different structural identity and has defaulted back to inactive. Structural identity is explained in [WWDC 2021 Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/). I reported this as bug [FB9977102](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5576747282071552) hopefully they fix it.

Another major problem with `NavigationLink` that it doesn't work when offscreen. E.g. in your sample code add lots of rows to fill up more than the screen. Scroll to top, wait one minute (so the picked updates), select first row, adjust the time to current time which will move the row to last in the list and off screen. You'll notice the `NavigationLink` has deactivated. People face this problem when trying to implement deep links and they can't activate a `NavigationLink` that is in a row that is off screen.

**Update 15th Nov 2022:** Apple replied to my feedback FB9977102 "this can be resolved by using the new Navigation APIs to avoid the view identity issues described." NavigationStack seems ok but NavigationSplitView has a row selection bug, see my [screen-capture](https://youtube.com/shorts/On_8alWwox8?feature=share).

Comment: Dr. Hall, thank you for your help again! I've tried giving `NavigationLink` an explicit identifier. I've used `objectID` of an `Item` like so `.id(item.objectID)`, but so far, no luck. The issue persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61153180/7337547

There is a two-year-old question that tackles somewhat of a similar issue. It concludes that this is a bug and that the body should not be called if a view is not currently displayed on the screen. Only when it reappears. And using your trick, I've inspected that the body is indeed being called. But the body is being called all the time. And the issue is there only when an item is moved to a different section. So it seems that this is a problem of view identity. And it's hard to believe that Apple wouldn't fix this bug that is two years old.

Comment: The solution in this post is to have a local model and update it only when the view reappears, but I don't see how we can do it with SectionedFetchRequest. We can't initialize empty FetchedResults, can we?

Comment: You can use a child context to make the edits without affecting the main context. However the problem will still occur if something else changes the main context, like a background task, e.g. sync.

Comment: Oh I remember that problem with favourites in Landmarks. Body does have to be called though because that’s just how SwiftUI works, it builds the hierarchy and using the result of the diff it decides what to update, add or remove from the screen.

Comment: I couldn't fix this so I reported the bug that NavigationLinks deactivate when the row moves between sections FB9977102

Comment: I'm already using child contexts. But that does not solve the issue since you have to eventually push up the changes to the main context when you dismiss the editor. Dr. Hall, thanks for your valuable help and for reporting this bug.

Comment: Correct, however you could rearchitect it so you create the child context when you push on the detail view. It would involve creating it in button action when the row is selected and then programatically activating the navigation link, I believe that is possible though.

Comment: Sorry thats currently impossible. It would need to be done in onAppear, task or a DynamicProperty's update func.